# How to do some initialization after all dependencies injected?

Tags: dependency-injection, playframework, guice, lifecycle

Is it possible in Play Framework to call some method of several singletons after all injections are done but before service is started? How to do it better?

Comment: Not sure about play framework but with hk2 every service has a well-defined lifecycle including the possibility of optional postConstruct and preDestroy method.  CDI has the same thing

Comment: You should be able to use some parts of the SPI (extensions) https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/InspectingModules

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you use Guice for [dependency injection](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaDependencyInjection)?
If that's the case, simply create a singleton object that depends on the relevant singletons and calls a method in its initializer.

Something like that:

```
  import javax.inject._


  @Singleton
  class ApplicationStart @Inject() (service1: Service1, service2: Service2, ...) {
       service1.initializeMethod()
       service2.otherInitMethod()
  }
```

Then make sure this object is eagerly initialized

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule

class StartModule extends AbstractModule {
  override def configure() = {
    bind(classOf[ApplicationStart]).asEagerSingleton()
  }
}
```

Guice will make sure to construct service1, service2 before it initializes the StartModule.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Guice for DI. I have a large and very dynamic project with dozens of dependencies regularly added and removed by the development team. I would not like to keep a "list"  of dependencies somewhere. An ideal solution would be to have an event like `injectionsDone` for Guice or `preStart` for Play Framework.